# count button pass the current page URL with pure javascript Ajax to the php variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I try to **pass the current page URL** (`window.location.href`) with **pure javascript Ajax** to the **php variable** `$_REQUEST['url']`. what am I doing wrong?

Counter.js:

```js
'use strict';
let clicks = document.querySelectorAll('.Counter-trigger'); // IE8
let voted = localStorage.getItem('voted');
let message = document.getElementById('Counter-message');
let count = document.getElementById('Counter-count');
let i;
let url;
let post;
let xhr;

for (let i = 0; i < clicks.length; i++) {
  clicks[i].onclick = function () {
    if (voted == 'voted') {
      message.innerHTML = "Sorry, ...!!";
    } else {
      let url = window.location.href;
      let post = url; // post string
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', './lib/Counter/CounterReq.php', true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState != 4 || xhr.status != 200) return;
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        message.innerHTML = "Thanks!!";
        count.innerHTML = +count.textContent+1;
      };
      xhr.send(post);
      localStorage.setItem('rate', 'voted');
      voted = 'voted';
    }
  }
}
```

CounterReq.php

```php
$url = $_REQUEST['url']; // posted from page
$origin = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH);
$file = '_Counter.txt'; // counts is saved in this document
$file_path = $origin.'_Counter.txt'; // counts is saved here
$count = file_get_contents($file_path);
if ($count == null){$count = 0; echo $count;
}
$count++; // increment count by 1
$handle = fopen($file_path, "w+");
flock($handle,LOCK_EX); // LOCK_EX (2) exclusive locking for write access
fwrite($handle, $count);
flock($handle,LOCK_UN); // LOCK_EX (3) Releases a lock
fclose($handle); // close file
```

index.php

```php
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // the path to the file
$file = '_Counter.txt'; // the number of vote is saved here
$file_path = $path.'_Counter.txt'; // the number of vote is saved here
if (!file_exists($file)) { // if the file does not exist, it will be created
    fopen($file, "w"); } // open file for writing only
    $count = file_get_contents($file_path); // reads entire file into a string
    if ($count == null){$count = 0;} // if the file empty, set count 0
?>
<button class="Counter-trigger">vote</button>
<span id="Counter-count">'.$count.'</span> times<br>
<div id="ClapsCounter-message"></div>
<script async src="./lib/Counter/Counter.js"></script>
```

### console.log:

**Notice**:  Undefined index: url in **/var/www/dist/lib/Counter/CounterReq.php** on line **5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice: Undefined index: url in /var/www/dist/lib/Counter/CounterReq.php on line 5

The notice means that your are looking for a an index in an associative array that does not exist.
Let's tackle that.

Store your data you want to send in a `FormData` object.

```
let url = window.location.href;
const data = new FormData()
data.set('url', url);
```

Modify your 'Content-Type' to `'multipart/form-data'` or remove it all the same. The `FormData` instance will automatically set the correct header.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
```

Send the data to the server in the `.send` method.

```
xhr.send(data);
```

Use the `$_POST` global array instead of `$_GET`, you are sending your data through the `POST` method so it will be in the former.

The data that you have sent to the server has now been processed as an associative array. Check if the key of `url` exists in and store it if it does.

```
$url = isset( $_POST['url'] ) ? $_POST['url'] : '';
```

Comment: thanks, have accepted your suggestion. Among other things, I deleted the //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type ',' application / x-www-form-urlencoded '); its work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to urlencode the variable you want to send and name it; change post to

```
let post = 'url=' + encodeURIComponent(url);
```

and it should work fine.

Edit: I didn't notice that you're using the `_GET` array instead of `_POST`. As the other answer says, make that change too.

However, it isn't necessary to use JSON; `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` works fine too.

Comment: sorry, its was a my mistake; the question was not correct. now: $_REQUEST['url'] instead of $_GET['url']